# Turn Django list of paths into PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, pythonpath

I'm trying to come up with a workaround for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646279/celery-error-no-module-named-billiard-forking-how-to-diagnose).

I'm deploying an application with Chef, and currently there is no PYTHONPATH set. This is fine for Django, which sets its own paths:

```
$ cat bin/django
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/opt/mytardis/releases/2737f42a91cd1b5d0a4b4c4609550fc586e351ab/eggs/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg',
    '/opt/mytardis/releases/2737f42a91cd1b5d0a4b4c4609550fc586e351ab/eggs/coverage-3.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/opt/mytardis/releases/2737f42a91cd1b5d0a4b4c4609550fc586e351ab/eggs/django_nose-1.1-py2.7.egg',
...
```

However, Celery launches 'python' processes directly, and fails because it can't find modules. In summary:

```
$ python -c from billiard.forking import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named billiard.forking

$ bin/django shell
>>> from billiard.forking import main
>>>
```

So I need to convert the list of paths set up in the Django script into a PYTHONPATH available to Python. And this conversion needs to be scriptable (because it's Chef).

So far I can only think of using Awk to munge the script into a giant "export PYTHONPATH=..." statement and put that in a .bashrc. There must be a better way?

Python 2.7.3, Django 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a simpler way:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/opt/app/current':`ls -d -1 /opt/app/current/eggs/* | tr '\n' ':'`
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative that we were looking at was to add something like this to the buildout.cfg

```
 [python_wrapper]
 recipe = zc.recipe.egg
 eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
 interpreter = python
```

and add `python_wrapper` to the `parts` list.

But the workaround that you tweeted (to version lock to an older version of celery) is better.  This is a celery bug, and it is better to wait for the developers to fix it.

(So we haven't tried the solution above to see if it actually works ...)